# Computing optimum efforts

Tags: optimization, nash-equilibrium

Consider the following cost function:

$$c(e_1, e_2) = (\beta_1e_1 + \beta_2e_2)^2$$

The value function is:

$$v = v_0 - [l_1(1-e_1) + l_2(1-e_2)]$$

How do I compute the optimum efforts $e_1$ and $e_2$, with $e_{i} \in [0,1]$ ? I seem to be ending up in an inconsistency.

If I look at $v - c = v_0 - [l_1(1-e_1) + l_2(1-e_2)] -  (\beta_1e_1 + \beta_2e_2)^2$, and then I take the partial derivative with respect to $e_1$ and $e_2$ respectively, I obtain:

$$\beta_1e_1^* + \beta_2e_2^* = \dfrac{l_1}{2\beta_1} = \dfrac{l_2}{2\beta_2}$$

What am I missing? Does the inconsistency simply mean that the optimal efforts are corner points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. The problem here is a corner solution.

Let us define the optimal combination $X^* = \beta_1e_1^* + \beta_2e_2^*$.

The first derivative gives you

$$X^* = \dfrac{l_1}{2\beta_1} $$

whereas the second gives you

$$X^* = \dfrac{l_2}{2\beta_2}$$

They can only be true "by chance". This is, **the existence of an interior solution cannot be assured for every possible parameterisation allowed by the parameter space.**

Actually, if you take a look at the two functions, this is clear. The cost function generate **linear** isoquants. You can check this [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%2By)%5E2%3D5). This is because the cost function is equivalent to $c = X^2$ and $X$ is a linear combination of both $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Similarly, the value function also gives **linear** isoquants. This is because the function has the form $e_1 = a + be_2$.

Then, the most likely case is that the isoquants will join in a corner. The interior solution happens just by chance. Notice that when this is the case, **any interior solution is optimal!** The equilibrium set is then infinite.